# Problema ao retornar dados com PDO do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma consulta que retorna as permissões de um determinado grupo de usuários do meu sistema. Utilizo MySQL com PHP. Meu comando SQL é o seguinte:

```
select
    p.Codigo, p.Descricao,
    (case when gp.CodGrupoUsuario is null then 0 else 1 end) as TemPermissao
from permissao p
left outer join grupopermissao gp
  on gp.CodPermissao = p.Codigo
 and gp.ativo = 1
 and gp.CodGrupoUsuario = :pCodGrupo
```

No meu banco de dados mysql (5.6.21) tenho duas permissões para um grupo que estou testando:

- 1 - Acessr o sistema: 1
- 2 - Cadastrar permissões: 0

Se eu executo o comando no banco de dados, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Quando rodo minha aplicação PHP, estou utilizando PDO (mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503) e retorno os meus dados utilizando "fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)". No PHP, os dados são retornados, porém o indicador de permissão (1 ou 0) está voltando sempre 0, conforme mostrado abaixo:

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
    [Codigo] => 1
    [Descricao] => Acessar o sistema
    [TemPermissao] => 0 )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
    [Codigo] => 2
    [Descricao] => Cadastrar permissões
    [TemPermissao] => 0 ) )
```

Ao instanciar minha conexão com o banco de dados estou utilizando:

- PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false
- PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES = false

Alguém pode me dizer porque a minha coluna "TemPermissao" não está retornando o valor correto? Já tentei de tudo e nada funcionou.

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Removi o `CASE` e o `OUTER`, ficando assim:

```
SELECT
    p.Codigo, p.Descricao,
    if(gp.CodGrupoUsuario is null, 0, 1) as TemPermissao
FROM permissao p
LEFT JOIN grupopermissao gp  ON 
    gp.CodPermissao = p.Codigo 
    and gp.ativo = 1 
    and gp.CodGrupoUsuario = :pCodGrupo
```